# Vue.js vuetify i18n : How to translate dynamically the Toolbar items?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I don't have any problem in localizing the components and views strings but I am lock into finding a way to localize dynamically the Toolbar items ( and of course the same items in the navigation drawer..

Currently they are displayed in App.vue as menuItems[i].title

```
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-xs-only">
      <v-btn flat :to="menuItems[0].link">
        <v-icon left>{{ menuItems[0].icon }}</v-icon>
        <span>{{ menuItems[0].title }}</span>
      </v-btn>
```

with the script:

```
    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          appName: 'myAPP',
          sideNav: false,
          menuItems: [
            { icon: 'home', title: 'Home', link: '/home' },
            { icon: 'info', title: 'About', menu: [{ title: 'Company', link: '/company' }, { title: 'Office', link: '/office' }] },
            { icon: 'people', title: 'Members', menu: [], link: '/members' },
            { icon: 'local_library', title: 'Blog', link: '/blog' },
            { icon: 'local_grocery_store', title: 'Shopping', link: '/shopping' }
          ]
        }
      },
      methods: {
          switchLocale: function (newLocale) {
            this.$store.dispatch('switchI18n', newLocale)
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Should I use a computed value ? or use directly $t() in the template ?

feedback, advices and links appreciated

**UPDATE**

**main.js**

```
Vue.filter('translate', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  value = 'lang.views.global.' + value.toString()
  return i18n.t(value)
})
```

**locales/i18n/en_US**

```
{
  "views": {
    "global": {
      "Home": "Home",
      "Section1": "Section 1",
      ..
```

Comment: Did you try `{{ $t("menuItems[0].title") }}`? what's wrong with that?

Comment: I will consider [vue filter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

Comment: @Sphinx If I use it , I get the string "menuItems[1].title" displayed ... not the translation.

Comment: @Sphin Your second comment IS the answer ! Can you set it as an answer , so I can vote for it ...   I used a global filter in my main.js .. awesome , never used filters before ...

Comment: @Sphinx . Ok, got it running fine ... see my UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue provides [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) to help us to format the common text.

So I think it will be one of your choices.

You can click above link to follow the guide to set up your filters.

**Edit:**

I just realized Vue-filters should not be dependent on this context [as the Vue author said](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5998). So updated my answer as below:

Then the codes will be like below:

```
// create vue-i18n instance
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: getDefaultLanguage(),
  messages: langs
})

// create global filter
Vue.filter('myLocale', function (value) {
  return i18n.t(value)
})
```

In your views or components:

```
<template>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-xs-only">
      <v-btn flat :to="menuItems[0].link">
        <v-icon left>{{ menuItems[0].icon }}</v-icon>
        <span>{{ menuItems[0].title | myLocale }}</span>
      </v-btn>
</template> 

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      appName: 'myAPP',
      sideNav: false,
      menuItems: [
        { icon: 'home', title: 'Home', link: '/home' },
        { icon: 'info', title: 'About', menu: [{ title: 'Company', link: '/company' }, { title: 'Office', link: '/office' }] },
        { icon: 'people', title: 'Members', menu: [], link: '/members' },
        { icon: 'local_library', title: 'Blog', link: '/blog' },
        { icon: 'local_grocery_store', title: 'Shopping', link: '/shopping' }
      ]
    }
  },
  filters: {
      myLocaleWhichNotWork: function (value) {
        return this.$t(value) // this won't work because filters should not be dependent on this context
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```